# How to use Ajax.ActionLink as POST in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I'm trying to delete entries from an index page in my ASP.NET MVC project, that's heavily base on the demo project, but I don't want to redirect to a delete page like the demo project is set up. I want to delete and just reload using a post method in my controller:

[image]

```
        // POST: Consumers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
        {
           // ...
        }
```

I tried it using an `@Html.ActionLink` which doesn't work as I've learned. So there quite a few very similar questions here on SO with (accepted) answers indicating that this supposedly works:

`@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Consumer", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })`

The only problem is that it doesn't work. If I do this then I get a 404 with the right URL but the wrong HTTP method

[image]

I know that the Ajax link is still firing off a GET despite its settings because if I relabel my POST method as a GET method then I'm stepping into it.

So does anybody know what I'm missing here???

Comment: Why it is a  big problem to remove POST from the action? There are ways to commit POST but it is much easier just to remove this attribute.

Comment: If I remove the HttpPost attribute then I essentially use a Get as a Post. Access requires authentication anyway, so it wouldn't be that bad. But it cannot be that hard to do a proper AJAX call. I'd just like to get it right

Comment: I am really wondering why do you think the POST is more right then GET. For example I have 20+years experince and use POST only if I need to send a lot of data which can be hard to place in a URL string.  In all another cases I prefer GET. And I don' t use any another methods at all and never  use any attributes like GET or POST in the action headers

Answer (score 1):

Action link is always generating GET method. So just remove POST from the action.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
 {
           // ...
 }
```

and IMHO  it is a much better idea  not to assign methods to the actions, since different browsers can generate different methods.